# linux dhcp server setting

Tags: linux, ubuntu-20.04

I want to allocate ip of each client belonging to two switches using dhcp server.[image]

The client ip of PG-DHCP-SERVER was assigned, but the client ip of PG-DHCP-SERVER2 was not assigned.
Are there any settings I am wrong or need additional settings?

```
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
ddns-update-style none;

subnet 10.11.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 {
     option subnet-mask 255.255.0.0;
     range 10.11.10.100 10.11.10.200;
}

subnet 10.12.30.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
    range 10.12.30.100. 10.12.30.200;
}
```

Comment: You have a good question, but you have posted to the wrong StackEachange site. I’m voting to close this question because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: Sorry.
Since this is a question that does not fit the purpose of the site, we will address it as a solution and ask a question on the site that was informed.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry.
Since this is a question that does not fit the purpose of the site, we will address it as a solution and ask a question on the site that was informed.